# SpEL function changes String

Tags: java, spring, annotations, spring-el

I am trying to take a String from properties, run an operation on it, then store it as a variable with the `@Value` annotation.  Unfortunately, when I use the `#{'${variable}'}` syntax that I need to use to use SpEL, the String changes.  If I have two double quotes (`""`), they are changed to a single double quote (`"`) which prevents me from deserializing the String.  How do I prevent Spring from removing that 2nd quotation mark?

```
myProperties.properties
myValue={"myWorkingKey": "Hi!", "myNonWorkingKey": ""}


MyClass.java
public class MyClass {

  @Value("#{'${myValue}'}")
  public void printWithSpEL(String withSpEL){
    System.out.println(withSpEL);
  }

  @Value("${myValue}")
  public void printWithOut(String without){
    System.out.println(without);
  }
}
```

result after startup:

```
{"myWorkingKey": "Hi!", "myNonWorkingKey": "}
{"myWorkingKey": "Hi!", "myNonWorkingKey": ""}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you need to use SpEL for such a simple value? The property placeholder is enough.

Or is this just an example based on something more complex.

With SpEL you need triple quotes:

```
myValue={"myWorkingKey": "Hi!", "myNonWorkingKey": """}
```

Comment: Yes, just the root issue from a larger String.  Thanks for the quick response!

Answer (score 0):

Why you want to load it into `String`? Load instead into `Map<String, String>`.

```
@Value("#{${myValue}}")
public void printWithSpEL(Map<String, String> withSpEL){
    System.out.println(withSpEL);
}
```